# A set of matrices and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> It is known that if $S = \{v_1, v_2,..., v_r\}$ is a set of vectors in $R^n$ and  $r>n$, then S is linearly dependent.

If I have a set of five $2 \times 2$ matrices $S=\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ can I use this rule to show linear dependence? I'm asking this because I'm not sure of the magnitude of the vector space. I know we say the vector space is $M_{22}$. Can we say that the size of the vector space is $2 \times 2 = 4$ and there five unknowns so we have linear dependence?

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Not size. Dimension. Which determines isomorphisms. Don't say it, show that it is so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you state is correct.

In general, the dimension (not magnitude) of the vector space of the $n×n$ matrices is $n^2$, 
with the canonical basis matrices:
$$(E_{ij}) := (δ_{ik}δ_{jl})_{k,l=1}^n.$$

(These matrices are $0$ everywhere, except the entry $i,j$.)

Additionally it is:
$$ℝ^{n×n} \cong ℝ^{n^2}.$$

Comment: aaaaaahhh, very nice @P.Siehr. Thanks for letting me know this.

Comment: Remark: That also works more general for $m×n$ matrices.

Comment: Cheers @P. Siehr